# Retrive Data from Data Extension

Tags: dataextensions, marketing-cloud

I need to Query the Triggered Sends in the data extension folder. Can I do that?

So the Hierarchy is like this.

```
- Data Extension 
   - Triggered Sends
      -  Parent Folder
        " Name of Data Extension to Query"
```

I need to write the SQL query to retrieve data from "Name of Data Extension to Query" DE, it gives me error as this DE is not a known data extension.
Is there any specific syntax for this ?

Comment: Can you post your query too please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely the cause of your issue lies in the spaces in the data extension name.

Two resolutions would work here -

1) **Preferred Method** - Rename this and all data extensions with spaces to either include underscores (or dashes) instead of the space (or completely delete the space).  This, while understandably, may cause headaches - but it's best practice when working with data tables to use underscores. It will save headaches in the long run.

Produces this:

```
SELECT * FROM Name_of_Data_Extension_to_Query
```

2) *Workable - but not as good* - Use brackets in your query.

```
SELECT * FROM [Name of Data Extension to Query]
```

Either way works, but you can save yourself hassle by naming them with the underscores.

Comment: ...as you said it was the problem with the name of my data extension. Thanks a lot for our help.

Comment: Great! Feel free to up vote and mark it answered.