# Data extension field name is invalid, multiple errors

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

**The Error**

> Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: ClaimRow("MatthewDataExtension", "isClaimed", "WebPromoCode", "StoreCouponCode", "Customer_No", @numberCustomer) MemberID: 7221103 JobID: 0 The Data Extension field name for a ClaimRow function call is invalid. A field of this name does not exist. Function Call: ClaimRow("MatthewDataExtension", "isClaimed", "WebPromoCode", "StoreCouponCode", "Customer_No", @numberCustomer) Data Extension Name: MatthewDataExtension Field Name: isClaimed Parameter Name: BoolClaimedColumnName Parameter Ordinal: 2 
> Invalid Content: 
> set @couponDataExtensionRow = ClaimRow("MatthewDataExtension", "isClaimed", "WebPromoCode", "StoreCouponCode", "Customer_No", @numberCustomer)

**The ampscript**

```
%%[
    var @numberCustomer
          set @numberCustomer = [Customer_No]

    var @couponDataExtensionRow
      set @couponDataExtensionRow = ClaimRow("MatthewDataExtension", "isClaimed", "WebPromoCode", "StoreCouponCode", "Customer_No", @numberCustomer)

    var @codeOnline
    var @barCode

    IF NOT EMPTY(@couponDataExtensionRow) THEN
          set @codeOnline = FIELD(@couponDataExtensionRow,"WebPromoCode")
          set @barCode = FIELD(@couponDataExtensionRow, "StoreCouponCode")
    ENDIF
]%%
```

**The Data Extension**

[image]

**The Actual Data**

[image]

**Research and other items**

I've checked [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57793/retrive-data-from-data-extension), but my data extension doesn't have spaces in the name.  I've also checked [the documentation for ClaimRow](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/ClaimRow.html), and I *thought* I had it set up correctly.  I'm seeing this error when I try to validate my email.  The `invalid content` appears to be for the `isClaimed` content.  Am I right in thinking that, and is `false` an invalid option there?  My apologies if it's something obvious, it's my first day with ampscript and Salesforce.

**Updated ampscript**

I updated the script as suggested, but I'm still getting the same errors:

```
%%[
    var @numberCustomer
          set @numberCustomer = AttributeValue("Customer_No")

    var @WebPromoCode
          set @WebPromoCode = AttributeValue("WebPromoCode")

    var @StoreCouponCode
          set @StoreCouponCode = AttributeValue("StoreCouponCode")

    var @couponDataExtensionRow
      set @couponDataExtensionRow = ClaimRow("MatthewDataExtension", "IsClaimed", "WebPromoCode", @WebPromoCode, "StoreCouponCode", @StoreCouponCode, "Customer_No", @numberCustomer)

    var @onlineCode
    var @barcode

    IF NOT EMPTY(@couponDataExtensionRow) THEN
          set @onlineCode = FIELD(@couponDataExtensionRow,"WebPromoCode")
          set @barcode = FIELD(@couponDataExtensionRow,"StoreCouponCode")
    ENDIF
]%%
```

The `isClaimed` column was changed in the DE to `IsClaimed`.

I've also tried a smaller `ClaimRow()`:

```
var @couponDataExtensionRow
      set @couponDataExtensionRow = ClaimRow("MatthewDataExtension", "IsClaimed", "Customer_No", @numberCustomer)
```

Which at least gives me a different error:

> Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: ClaimRow("MatthewDataExtension", "IsClaimed", "Customer_No", @numberCustomer) MemberID: 7221103 JobID: 0 The Data Extension field name for a ClaimRow function call is invalid. A field of this name does not exist. Function Call: ClaimRow("MatthewDataExtension", "IsClaimed", "Customer_No", @numberCustomer) Data Extension Name: MatthewDataExtension Field Name: IsClaimed Parameter Name: BoolClaimedColumnName Parameter Ordinal: 2 
> Invalid Content: 
> set @couponDataExtensionRow = ClaimRow("MatthewDataExtension", "IsClaimed", "Customer_No", @numberCustomer)

Comment: I'd delete your coupon data extension and recreate it with a primary key.

Comment: You think adding it after the fact might be causing issues?  I'll do that first thing in the morning and post the result.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Not sure how that fixed it, but re-creating the DE and the tips below got it.  Answer accepted, and thanks for the help!

Comment: Sweet.  I saw your MID (7221103) and took a peek at the server error log and noticed some PK errors.  Occasionally DE primary key changes will error out without any indication in the UI.  Awesome, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest setting a primary key on your `MatthewDataExtension` Data Extension, since the `ClaimRow()` function is doing an update.

Also, every pair of `ClaimRow()` parameters after the 2nd needs to be the variable name and then the variable value -- in order to retrieve the proper row.  So if you're going to update `WebPromoCode` and `StoreCouponCode`, your function would be this:

```
%%[

var @numberCustomer
var @WebPromoCode
var @StoreCouponCode
set @numberCustomer = AttributeValue("Customer_No")
set @WebPromoCode = AttributeValue("WebPromoCode")
set @StoreCouponCode = AttributeValue("StoreCouponCode")

set @couponDataExtensionRow = ClaimRow("MatthewDataExtension", "isClaimed", "WebPromoCode", @WebPromoCode, "StoreCouponCode", @StoreCouponCode , "Customer_No", @numberCustomer)

/* Snip */ 

]%%
```

If it helps, here's my go-to coupon claiming AMPScript:

```
%%[

var @couponRow, @couponCode, @rows, @row, @emailaddr

set @emailaddr = AttributeValue("emailaddr")

set @rows = LookupRows("couponCodes","EmailAddress",@emailaddr)

if rowcount(@rows) > 0 then
  set @row = Row(@rows,1)
  set @couponCode= field(@row,"couponCode")
else

    if _messagecontext == "PREVIEW" then
           set @couponCode = "XX TEST XX"
    else

      set @couponRow = ClaimRow("couponCodes","IsClaimed","EmailAddress",emailaddr) 

          if empty(@couponRow) then
             /* You can do other error handling here if you want.*/
             /* This aborts the send */
             raiseError("no more coupons available")
          else 
             set @couponCode= field(@couponRow,"couponCode") 
          endif

    endif 

endif

]%%

Here's your coupon code: %%=v(@couponCode)=%%
```

There are a few more details about the Data Extension on in [my blog post on the subject](http://sprignaturemoves.com/coupon-claiming-in-ampscript/).

Comment: That helps.  I set the key as recommended.  What exactly does the `AttributeValue("...")` do when declaring and setting the variables?  Thanks for looking into this btw!

Comment: `AttributeValue()` will return an empty string if the Profile Attribute or sending Data Extension column doesn't exist.  If you don't use it and the attribute doesn't exist, your email will blow up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was exactly what the error was telling you the field does not exist in your DE.

Field name in your screenshot of the DE **"IsCaimed"**, Lookup field - **IsClaimed**

If you just changed the field name, the script would've run. Assume that when you recreated, the field name was spelled correctly. :)